# How to Store Multiple Options selected by User in a Table

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design

So I want my users to be able to restrict who may contact them.

There are several factors they should be able to filter, including Age (e.g. Must be between 18 - 29), income (must earn between $25,000 - $60,000), what they're looking for (e.g. Friendship, Hang out, etc.), what drugs they do (Marijuana, Meth, Cocaine, etc), etc.

The problem is, I want them to be able to select and store multiple choices for some of the criteria (e.g. drugs), but I do not know how I should store that in the DB or how I should structure the table to best accomplish that.

For example, how would I store a user's row that for "drugs" chose "Marijuana", "Cocaine", and "Heroin" within this context?  Would I simply store those as comma-separated values in the "Drugs" column?  Or should I do it in a completely different way?

What would be the best way to do this (considering I will obviously have to retrieve and check this information every time a user wants to contact another user) and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, don't store the values in CSV format in the database. Instead create a [join table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) called `user_drug` and store one row for each user/drug combination:

```
user
id    name  income
1     Foo   10000
2     Bar   20000
3     Baz   30000

drug
id    name
1     Marijuana
2     Cocaine
3     Heroin

user_drug
user_id drug_id
1       1
1       2
2       1       
2       3
3       3
```

Comment: Interesting.  But what about the main table with all the restrictions, not just drugs (which is just one "column") ?

Comment: Thanks for the edit, but I'm still confused.  I need to create a new table of RESTRICTIONS, which will have a column for each user's restriction.  Those columns will include age, income, looking for, drugs, etc.  Some of those columns (looking for, drugs, etc.) might contain multiple choices.  I still do not understand how to structure that table RESTRICTIONS in that way.  Sorry I'm dense, and I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @Programmer: You will need a separate join table for each "column" that can contain multiple values. Though I think just min and max values should be sufficient for age and income. Don't you agree? Seems a bit odd to be looking for 21-30 or 41-50 but not 31-40...

Comment: OK, so I need a join table for each multiple choice column.  Got it.  I see how you structured the user_drug join table, for example, but what does the drug column on the RESTRICTIONS table look like? (I've never dealt with join tables)

Comment: There is no drug column on the RESTRICTIONS table. All the values are stored in the join table.

Comment: OK, so to organize each users restriction criteria, I will need to create RESTRICTIONS table for each singular (non-multiple) criteria, but also additional Join Tables for each multiple-criteria, is that correct?  If so, that sounds quite complicated because all the criteria is not in the same table, and fetching all of a users criteria would seem to involve multiple queries.  Is this the best way to go about it?  If so, I'll go this route.

Answer (score 1):

A DB column (at least theorethically) should **NOT** hold multiple values. Unfortunately, there are some programmers that store multiple values in a single column (values separated by comma for examples) - those programmers (in most cases) destroy the concept of DB and SQL.

I suggest you to read about *[Database Normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)* to get a start in organizing your tables. And, do your best to achieve the *[Codd's Third Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form)*

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this:

```
criterium
------------
user_id type          value
1       AGE_MIN       18
1       AGE_MAX       29
1       INCOME_MIN    25000
1       INCOME_MAX    60000
1       DRUGS         Marijuana
1       DRUGS         Meth
```

Comment: How do you have two columns with the same name?

Comment: This is enum values ('AGE_MIN', 'AGE_MAX', 'INCOME_MIN', 'INCOME_MAX', 'DRUGS' ... ), so user with id 1 have criterium for Drugs 'Marijuana' and 'Meth'.

Comment: I'm not familiar with "enum values".   How would you I structure the RESTRICTIONS table in this way considering some values can have multiple choices (e.g. drugs, looking for, etc.)?

Comment: [Enum types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html) means that one record in this column will have only one value from enum list. Fro multiple choice you will need to insert multiple records (like last two records in my example). Maybe this is not best solution but easy to implement and do require just one table.